# count bubble in Bubble sort,how to get this count in less time

Tags: python, bubble-sort

How to get this count in less time.
I got time to exceed in this type if any possibility to get it with less time.

```py
swaped = True
count = 0
while swaped != False:
    swaped = False
    **count** = **count**+1
    # here is bubble count
    for i in range(0, N-1):
        if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]):
            temp = arr[i]
            arr[i] = arr[i+1]
            arr[i+1] = temp
            swaped = True

print(count)
```

Comment: Just to be clear you want to speed up the bubble sort algorithm? To count it’s bubbles?

Comment: @PovilasKirna doesn't  one thing will lead to another?

Comment: I'm sorry @Ashwani but to my knowledge your bubble sort algorithm is as optimised as it can be. So there is only left to change the algorithm to something faster :)

Comment: No, I don't want to optimize the bubble sort algorithm I just want that count like for example if we have an array [5 1 2 3 4] in this algorithm takes O(5) time but we need to calculate that count=1 that may we can get in less time

Comment: @Dharmpaaji if you only wants the count then and not interested in the method in which count is calculated then you can make use of merge sort to calculate the counts. The bubble sort will take O(n^2) but by using merge sort you can calculate the counts using O(nlogn) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The code for bubble sort that you have written is as optimized as it can be. So you need to find alternative for the algorithm to serve the purpose. One of the algorithm to accomplish the number of swaps is to use the merge sort. You can make use of merge sort to calculate the swaps in O(nlogn) time. The problem is known as inversion counts. I have provided a code sample below to accomplish this in O(nlogn) time.

```
def mergeSort(arr, n): 
    temp_arr = [0]*n 
    return tmergeSort(arr, temp_arr, 0, n-1) 

# This Function will use MergeSort to count inversions 

def tmergeSort(arr, temp_arr, left, right): 

    # Inversions_count
    inv_count = 0

    if left < right: 

        # Mid of an array
        mid = (left + right)//2

        # calculating inversions_count for the left array.
        inv_count = tmergeSort(arr, temp_arr, left, mid) 

        # calculating inversions_count for the right array.
        inv_count += tmergeSort(arr, temp_arr, mid + 1, right) 

        # Merging two sorted arrays.
        inv_count += merge(arr, temp_arr, left, mid, right) 
    return inv_count 

# Merging two sorted arrays. 
def merge(arr, temp_arr, left, mid, right): 
    i = left     
    j = mid + 1 
    k = left      
    inv_count = 0
 
    while i <= mid and j <= right: 

        # No inversion if arr[i] <= arr[j] 

        if arr[i] <= arr[j]: 
            temp_arr[k] = arr[i] 
            k += 1
            i += 1
        else: 
            # Inversion will occur if arr[i] > arr[j] 
            temp_arr[k] = arr[j] 
            inv_count += (mid-i + 1) 
            k += 1
            j += 1

    # The remaining elements of left array are copied
    while i <= mid: 
        temp_arr[k] = arr[i] 
        k += 1
        i += 1

    # The remaining elements of right array are copied
    while j <= right: 
        temp_arr[k] = arr[j] 
        k += 1
        j += 1

    for loop_var in range(left, right + 1): 
        arr[loop_var] = temp_arr[loop_var] 
        
    return inv_count 
  
# Given array is 
arr = [83, 20, 9, 50, 115, 61, 17] 
n = len(arr) 
result = mergeSort(arr, n) 
print("Inversions_count =", result)
```